# Максимум в неупорядоченном массиве через рекурсию

Tags: c#, массивы, рекурсия

Использовать Linq запрещено. Мой код не работает, когда массив огромный (10_000_000 ).

выпадает вот такая ошибка
Stack overflow.
Repeat 16069 times

когда массив больше 10_000

есть мысли, что нужно делить исходный массив на части, и обрабатывать уже эти части. Но вообще нет идеи, как это через рекурсию реализовать. Циклы использовать нельзя.

```
class Program
{
    public static int FindMaximum(int[] array)
    {
        if (array is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{array} is null");
        }

        if (array.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{array} is empty");
        }

        int result = array[0];

        int lastNumber = array.Length - 1;

        return FindMaximumOne(array, result, 0, lastNumber);
    }

    public static int FindMaximumOne(int[] array, int result, int i, int lastNumber)
    {
        if (i >= lastNumber)
        {
            return result;
        }

        if (array[i] > result)
        {
            result = array[i];
        }

        if(array[lastNumber] > result)
        {
            result = array[lastNumber];
        }

        i++;
        lastNumber--;

        return FindMaximumOne(array, result, i, lastNumber);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[] { -50, -25, -20, -5, -500, -100 };

        Console.WriteLine(FindMaximum(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: есть вероятность, что C# или даже CLR не поддерживают оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Попробуй запустить в release режиме.

Comment: просто я только еще учусь. И к сожалению даже не слышал такого понятия, как хвостовая рекурсия. Но я погуглю. Спасибо.

Comment: просто алгоритм работает с небольшими цифрами. Нужно как-то обыграть огромные числа

Comment: @Grundy: CLR точно поддерживает, иначе бы F# не существовал

Comment: @VladD, не, там может быть на уровня языка/компилятора поддержка :-) из того что я нашел, было обсуждение что C# как-то сам выбирает нужно оптимизировать или нет

Comment: @Grundy чтобы перебрать int.MaxValue элементов, при делении массива пополам потребуется глубина всего в 32 вызова. Это детские шалости для стека даже размером в мегабайт. Так что здесь безо всяких оптимизаций всё сработает. Другой вопрос: оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии в C# действительно (пока) нет, а вот в F# - есть. Так что CLR тут точно не при чем.

Comment: @Grundy: Компилятор, кстати, достаточно умный: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKBuPIE4AKAFSm3wAcIAbASwB2MJgFYAlGIDcNGoIwACNh278hTOfIFj5AXgB8i7Hx4AlGGCYC088lJnUNLI6fPqBCq/I3YwYMTQBvGnkQrwAzeUtdHXkABn9qUKT5YgB2eR8waUTkkODQtMNjMwsBeTgba0z5ACp5UjtqAF8aIA= Превратил рекурсию в while, то есть по сути провёл tail call elimination.

Comment: @aepot: На уровне JIT есть (Release/x64), смотрите пример в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: @VladD значит я ошибся. Спасибо.

Comment: Но официальной поддержки нету пока в C#: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2544, https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2304

Comment: @aepot: Вы не ошиблись в том смысле, что официальных гарантий нет. Но во многих случаях JIT таки проводит эту оптимизацию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы за один рекурсивный вызов отсекаете 2 элемента массива, потому на больших массивах у вас переполняется стек. Отсекайте на каждой итерации хотя бы половину, тогда глубина стека вам не будет помехой, пример

```
public static int FindMax(int[] array)
{
    return FindMax(array, 0, array.Length - 1);
}

public static int FindMax(int[] array, int start, int end)
{   
    if (end - start <= 1) return Math.Max(array[start], array[end]);    
    var mid = start + (end - start)/2;  
    return Math.Max(FindMax(array, start, mid), FindMax(array, mid, end));
}
```